# Berkovich analytifications and non-archimedean geometry of Transseries

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, geometry, number-theory

In Transseries and Real Differential Algebra by Joris van der Hoeven it is said that Transseries admit a rich non-Archimedean geometry (somewhere on page 13), but since the book isn't about that, nothing specifically is said on this. My question:

- Are there current research on the way in describing those geometries. For example, what is $(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{T}}^1)^{an}$ is going to be like, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the field of Transseries. Since $\mathbb{T}$ is somewhat all-encompassing (I believe van der Hoeven suggests that the Surreals are naturally included in it), it should be interesting doing geometry with that as a groundfield.